# Runtime errror with 100000 recursive calls in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, windows-10, runtime-error, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to run this code in C++14 on Cygwin and Mingw in Windows 10 but in both I am getting runtime error. But on Ubuntu 16.04 it runs without any problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int rec(int n){
    if(n == 0) return 0; 
    return 1 + rec(n-1); 
}

int main(){
    int k = 123456;
    cout << rec(k) << endl; 
    return 0 ;
}
```

But if I change the value of k to some number in 10^4 it works even on windows 10, like k = 12345.
What could be the reason behind this strange behavior?

Comment: The fact each recursive call costs some amount of memory, and your runtime environment only has so much to give. That's why one should avoid deep recursion.

Comment: Limited stack size. Obviously.

Comment: You are blowing up the stack.

Comment: My system has 4 GB RAM. So, why would the stack get depleted so quickly?

Comment: But the same code runs on Ubuntu in the same system. So, is the stack size OS dependent?

Comment: @taraprasad73 Why not OS dependent?

Comment: Yes and no. You can configure how much stack is allocated to the process (it's in the compilation options in GCC, for instance). How it's done is indeed OS and compiler dependent.

Comment: On linux the maximum stack size can be configured with ulimit.

Comment: The answer is in the name of this site: Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call stack is indeed limited, and its limit depends upon the computer and the OS (as a rule of thumb only: 1 Megabyte on Windows, 8 Megabytes on Linux).

You could use, on Linux, [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) to change the size of the call stack (e.g. with  `ulimit` builtin in your shell).

If you ask your compiler to optimize, e.g. compile with `g++ -O3 -fverbose-asm -S`, you'll see that `rec` is no more compiled as a recursive function

Answer (score 1):

Each recursive function call occupies some space in the stack. Different OS's manage RAM differently, and it's obvious that Windows 10 isn't maintaining a stack that's as big as the one that Ubuntu maintains. Maybe there's a way to tweak stack size but I'm not sure for Windows.